# Read blank line C++

Tags: c++, cin

I am in a situation where i had a loop and everytime it reads a string but I dont know how to read blank input i.e if user enter nothing and hit enter, it remains there.

I want to read that as string and move to next input
below is the code

```
int times = 4;
while(times--)
{
    string str;
    cin>>str;
    ---then some other code to play with the string---
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need to read the entire line using getline(). Then you would need to tokenize the strings read.

Here is a reference on using [getline](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/istream/getline/) and tokenizing using [stringstream](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/stringstream/).

Answer (score 3):

```
char blankline[100];
int times = 4;
while(times--)
{
    //read a blank line
    cin.getline(blankline,100);
    ---then some other code to play with the string---
}
```