# C++ voting program help (beginner)!

Tags: c++, voting-system

Im new at cpp and i try to train myself with a little voting program.
You give in the parties and then the votes of the party.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string sInput = " ";
    string sName1 = " ";
    string sName2 = " ";
    int iParty1 = 0;
    int iParty2 = 0;

    cout << "Name of the first party: ";
    cin >> sName1;
    cout << "Name of the second party: ";
    cin >> sName2;

    while (sInput != "")
    {
        cout << "Your vote: ";
        cin >> sInput;
        cout << endl;
        if (sInput == sName1)
        {
            iParty1++;
        }
        else
        {
            if (sInput == sName2)
            {
                iParty2++;
            }
            else
            {
                cout << "Wrong Input" << endl;
            }
        }

    }
    cout << sName1 << ": " << iParty1 << endl;
    cout << sName2 << ": " << iParty2 << endl;
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

So you see the while loop. I want the program stop if i only press enter.
But when i do it nothing happens. Why? Give me a clue!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Read blank line C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5077999/read-blank-line-c)

Comment: I think that this is because `sInput != ""` is true. When you hit the enter key, the value of `sInput` is `\n`, as this is not the case the program continues. You can stop it with a `Control + C`.

Comment: You initialized sInput to "", then require it to be something else to enter the while loop. The while loop NEVER triggers.

Answer (score 0):

Change your input function so that it reads in the entire line via `std::cin` rather than a tokenized string. You'll need to consider this read method since there can be spaces in the instream. Also, your Wrong Input code fires when you just put a blank line.

Here's a fixed version:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string sInput = " ";
    string sName1 = " ";
    string sName2 = " ";
    int iParty1 = 0;
    int iParty2 = 0;

    cout << "Name of the first party: ";
    cin >> sName1;
    cout << "Name of the second party: ";
    cin >> sName2;
    cin.ignore();

    while (sInput != "")
    {
        cout << "Your vote: ";
        getline(cin, sInput);
        cout << endl;
        if (sInput == sName1)
        {
            iParty1++;
        }
        else
        {
            if (sInput == sName2)
            {
                iParty2++;
            }
            else
            {
                cout << "Wrong Input" << endl;
            }
        }

    }
    cout << sName1 << ": " << iParty1 << endl;
    cout << sName2 << ": " << iParty2 << endl;
    getchar();
    return;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. It works. put i have to write a new if so it doesnt print wromg input when i presss enter. put thats not hard.;-D